# cfgrid format=flash is not displaying the result

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I was trying with cfgrid tag with format=flash for displaying query result.Its not displaying the output but generating the grid. the sample code i tried is:

```
<cfquery name = "GetCourses" dataSource = "cfdocexamples"> 
    SELECT Course_ID, Dept_ID, CorNumber, 
    CorName, CorLevel 
    FROM CourseList 
    ORDER by Dept_ID ASC, CorNumber ASC 
</cfquery> 

<h3>cfgrid Example</h3> 
<i>Currently available courses</i> 
<!--- cfgrid must be inside a cfform tag. ---> 
<cfform> 
 <cfgrid name = "FirstGrid" format="flash"  
    height="320" width="580" 
    font="Tahoma" fontsize="12" 
    query = "GetCourses"> 
 </cfgrid> 
</cfform>
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? (For what it is worth, the flash version of cfgrid is dreadful. You might be better off using the HTML version, or, better yet, using a 3rd party grid like jqGrid.)

Comment: I am using CF 9. since the requirement is in flash format..i was trying with the same. is there any other option to do the same?

Comment: Is this for a client or work project? If it is....you need to convince them that the Flash grid is NOT a good idea...in fact, it is an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: @shemy did you find a solution for this?